# Getting an error http500

Tags: mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I'm creating a JSP online exam project and made a page of student registration but I'm getting an error at `stmt.executeUpdate(q)` where `q` is my query which is correct. So can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-themes.css"/>
        <title>Student Sign Up</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%@include file="header.jsp" %>

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">        
                <form action="student.jsp">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-2">
                            <h3>Name</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                             <h3><input type="text" required class="form-control" name="sname"></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-2">
                            <h3>Email</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <h3><input type="text" required  class="form-control" name="semail" ></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-2">
                            <h3>Mobile No.</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <h3><input type="text" required  class="form-control" name="smobile"> </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-2">
                            <h3>Password</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <h3><input type="password" required  class="form-control" name="spass"></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-2">
                            <h3>Confirm Password</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <h3><input type="password"  required class="form-control" name="scpass"></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-6 col-lg-2">
                            <h3><input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="form-control" ></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my query page where I'm storing my student data into MySql student table:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" language="java"  pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Student confirm</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        String sname=request.getParameter("sname");

        String semail=request.getParameter("semail");
        String smobile=request.getParameter("smobile");
        String spass=request.getParameter("spass");

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/exam","root","password");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

        String q="insert into student(sname,contact,email,password) values('"+sname+"',"+smobile+",'"+semail+"','"+spass+"')";
        //out.print(q); 
        stmt.executeUpdate(q);
        con.close();
        %>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>          
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Error code 500 means there is an internal server error. Can you add more details on your server configuration?

Comment: Also, it would be a great idea to change over to prepared statements. you are leaving yourself up to being attacked this way

Comment: Can you tell me how to use prepared stmt over this please.

Comment: What does the error say?  Somewhere there is an error log - what is your application server?

Comment: missing `'` on `smobile` value for column `contact`?